# Conditional append of strings on fields in a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I am trying to convert a csv file like below with bash scripts. Headers and structures are always the same.

Source csv file:

```
name,title,department,score 
Jason,HR Manager,HR,10 
Alice,IT Director,Technology and Ops,8 
Jack,Network Team Lead,Technology and Ops,9
```

Conditional values (will change depending on the requirements)

```
Real_name=name
Real_title=title
Real_department=department
Real_score=score
```

Now I am trying to get the following result without the first row and values are now separated by spaces if each header matches those conditional values:

```
Real_name=Jason Real_title=HR Manager Real_department=HR Real_score=10
Real_name=Alice Real_title=IT Director Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=8
Real_name=Jack Real_title=Network Team Lead Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=9
```

I know this can be done with awk but my awk knowledge is limited. I tried the following to replace the first line but still don't know how to expand on it

```
awk "{$1="test "$1;print}' my_sample_file
```

Updated: I can’t seem to make it work with input from a file with conditional values. Just thinking about a better and easy to maintain approach where those values will not necessarily be the same all the time. Could be MOD_title, MOD_name, etc. Instead of Real_title, Real_name, etc.

Comment: Where should it be the conditional check? In one of the columns of the CSV? An external conditional check (a stupid example, if today is monday then column name must be MOD_...

Comment: I was thinking of using a txt file with conditional values. And then get awk to read it directly and then print out same output. This will take a few more lines of code I think but still can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you weren't missing all that much :)

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{printf "Real_name=%s Real_title=%s Real_department=%s Real_score=%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' my_sample_file 
Real_name=Jason Real_title=HR Manager Real_department=HR Real_score=10 
Real_name=Alice Real_title=IT Director Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=8 
Real_name=Jack Real_title=Network Team Lead Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=9
```

Comment: To make it clean and easier to change the conditional values, I’m thinking of putting them in a separate location (file in same directory or a sub section in same script) where awk can read and achieve the same goal. Thoughts?

Comment: Accepted this answer as it helped my figure out the issue before my edit. Thanks @tink

Answer (score 0):

With Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is very clean and easy

```
mlr --icsv --ofs " " rename -r '(.*),Real_\1' input.txt
```

to have

```
Real_name=Jason Real_title=HR Manager Real_department=HR Real_score=10
Real_name=Alice Real_title=IT Director Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=8
Real_name=Jack Real_title=Network Team Lead Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=9
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Looks very clean and short.

Comment: hi @Mikado09 please make me know if you have any problems

Comment: the only thing is I can’t seem to make it work with input from a file with conditional values. Just thinking about a better and easy to maintain approach where those values will not necessarily be the same. Could be MOD_title, MOD_name, etc. Instead of Real_title, Real_name, etc.

Comment: @Mikado09 please edit your question, adding a note about conditional values, with an input file ant output file examples, and I think it's possible to adapt my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        h[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "Real_%s=%s%s", h[i], $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Real_name=Jason Real_title=HR Manager Real_department=HR Real_score=10
Real_name=Alice Real_title=IT Director Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=8
Real_name=Jack Real_title=Network Team Lead Real_department=Technology and Ops Real_score=9
```

Comment: Worked but when the conditional values are not “Real_*” anymore, I’m thinking of putting them in a separate location (file in same directory or a sub section in same script) where awk can read and achieve the same goal. Just so that it can be updated easier. Thoughts?

Comment: It's only software so whatever way you want to do it is fine. Accept an answer to this question and ask a new one if you need help with that.

Comment: That's disappointing since some of us put effort into answering the question you asked so accepting one of those answers and asking a new question would have been a way to thank the people who did that and would have given you a better chance of getting an answer to your new question. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are generally frowned upon.

Comment: I don't understand why you had to feel the need to downgrade my post. The gist of the question still remains the same. I added an extra piece that shouldn't really change anything drastically and I think the mods here don't appreciate posting same question though

Comment: Because you already changed it once (and so may change it again) and by doing so invalidated all of the answers that people posted to try to help you. You are wrong in thinking that the change you made is insignificant. I advised you on how to handle that change and you chose to ignore that advice thereby changing what was a reasonable question with decent answers for that question into a chameleon question with answers that now do not answer the question as written and so will waste the time of people with similar questions trying to find answers in future. My downvote is a warning to others.

Comment: If you put your question back as it was and accept one of the answers (any of them, I don't care) then I'd remove my downvote as it'd no longer be appropriate.

Comment: Well you can choose to ignore my post though. Thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: It's too late to ignore it, I already tried to help you. With your updated question, if it wasn't downvoted then others reading it and seeing our answers would be justified in downvoting our answers since they no longer answer the question. At least now there's an indication that there's some problem with the question and not just that we threw out a bunch of useless answers. IMHO expecting us to update our answers or delete them as your question changes to avoid getting downvoted and/or wasting other readers' time is unreasonable. You're welcome.

Comment: Cool. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: No problem and please don't take this the wrong way as I really do mean it constructively but I see that all of [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4962567/mikado09) so far have been downvoted so you may be misunderstanding something about how to get the best out of this forum and could possibly benefit from reading [ask].

Comment: Thanks Ed. I will take a further look